# Cocos2d crash while using [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end] in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have prepared a game using cocos2d. The app is UIView template based. The actual problem is that, the apps crashing on moving from one view controller to another view controller. The game board is prepared using cocos2d. While moving from the view controller which contains Cocos2d screen to another view controller, I am using **[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end]**
to end the director. This code is running without any errors on iOS6 & below. But when I running the same code on iOS7, the app's crashing giving the following error.

```
<i>*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView context]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17804f40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x034205e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e368b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x034bd903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0341090b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x034104ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Hood Wordz With Frendz              0x00158ef1 -[CCTextureCache init] + 545
    6   Hood Wordz With Frendz              0x00158b58 +[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] + 88
    7   Hood Wordz With Frendz              0x000f6d19 -[CCDirector createStatsLabel] + 57
    8   Hood Wordz With Frendz              0x000f561d -[CCDirector setView:] + 365
    9   Hood Wordz With Frendz              0x000b6d48 -[CCDirectorIOS setView:] + 104
    10  UIKit                               0x01aaf42b -[UIViewController loadView] + 284
    11  UIKit                               0x01aaf73e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    12  UIKit                               0x01ad51a5 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 39
    13  UIKit                               0x01ad56bb -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 235
    14  UIKit                               0x01ad57b3 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 78
    15  UIKit                               0x01ad672c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 645
    16  UIKit                               0x01ad7349 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    17  UIKit                               0x01c1039d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    18  UIKit                               0x01a06dd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e4881f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    20  QuartzCore                          0x015c772a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    21  QuartzCore                          0x015bb514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    22  QuartzCore                          0x015bb380 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    23  QuartzCore                          0x01523156 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    24  QuartzCore                          0x015244e1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    25  QuartzCore                          0x01524bb4 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x033e853e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x033e848f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x033c63b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x033c5b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x033c594b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x04eca9d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x04eca7fe GSEventRun + 104
    33  UIKit                               0x0199c94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    34  Hood Wordz With Frendz              0x0000313d main + 141
    35  Hood Wordz With Frendz              0x000030a5 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException</i>
```

Anyone of you guys who knows why this is happening, please help me with this.

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint set in Xcode? If you do that, you'll see and can post the actual line of the crash and which unrecognized selector was sent to which object. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: Also, are you running this on a device or simulator?

Comment: @microslop It's crashing on device & simulator as well ...

Comment: I have applied the breakpoint & it's actually crashing in the CCTextureCahe.m class executing _auxGLcontext = [[EAGLContext alloc]   initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2    sharegroup:[[view context] sharegroup]]; line.